# How to get access to state with higher order component

Tags: reactjs, redux, higher-order-components

I want to create a higher order component that checks if a user has been logged in. If they have, I show the component if not, I want to redirect them to the login page.

can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's the HOC:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const withAuthentication = (Component) => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log(this.props.sessionId);
    }

    render() {
      return this.props.sessionId ? <Component {...this.props} /> : null;
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    sessionId: state.auth.userInfo.authUserInfo.sessionId
  })
  return connect(mapStateToProps, null)(WithAuthentication);
}

export default withAuthentication;
```

then I call it like this:

```
....
import withAuthentication from './containers/withAuthentication';
const Hello = () => <h1> Hello</h1>;
....
<Route path="/" component={ withAuthentication(Hello) }/>
```

I stripped more code that I think is unrelated to this...

TIA for you help!

Update: The code that is causing the propblem seems to be this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
sessionId: state.auth.userInfo.authUserInfo.sessionId
})
```

The error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sessionId' of undefined`

Comment: Whats the error/problem or how is it working incorrectly?

Comment: The error that comes up is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sessionId' of undefined` points to this block of code: `const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
> 16 |     sessionId: state.auth.userInfo.authUserInfo.sessionId
  17 |   })`

Comment: Your redux state for property `auth.userInfo.authUserInfo` isnt defined prior to this component being rendered

Comment: Well I figured that much - do you have an answer you'd be able to share with me?

Comment: I don't know the rest of how your application works. It's up to you to find where you set this redux state property `auth.userInfo.authUserInfo` and ensure it is set before rendering the component

Answer (score 0):

So basically, what you are doing in nesting one component into another i.e. a Functional component returning another component after some logical level verification.
What you are doing seems good. You should be able to access the props(not State), in a functional component like this

```
let aComponent(props)=>{
    return <p>{props.name}'s logged in status is {props.loggedIn}</p>
}
```

if you are using the component like this

```
<aComponent title="Hello" loggedIn={this.props.isLoggedIn}/> //isLoggedIn from redux store
```

Also, If the Logical/Authentication verification fails in `withAuthentication`, you should call the router API to navigate to your desired page.
i.e.
you should call this, if you are using `react-router`

```
this.props.router.push('/login')
```

Comment: Hi Manjot, thanks for replying. I'm sorry it's kind of hard to follow - are you saying the is logged in check should happen in the child of the hoc? Would that negate the necessity of the HOC?

Comment: Hi @AtlanteAvila, Saw your error there
. Try Initialising the userInfo state in your auth reducer as follows.
`initialState=
  {
    userInfo:{
      sessionId:''
    }
  }`

Comment: The error is occuring, because, your auth action is unable to populate the auth reducer state of userInfo, before being accessed by the component. It would be better if you can share your auth reducer snippet too